# possible ExtraArgs values in boto3 s3 client copy function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

> ExtraArgs (dict) -- Extra arguments that may be passed to the client operation

I'm looking at the documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy and I couldn't see any information on what possible values can we pass for this parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html#the-extraargs-parameter

Answer (score 4):

From Boto3 1.26.161 documentation:

Note that the docs Copy() API Call mentions that it allows ALLOWED_DOWNLOAD_ARGS

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer.ALLOWED_DOWNLOAD_ARGS

```
ALLOWED_DOWNLOAD_ARGS = ['ChecksumMode', 'VersionId', 'SSECustomerAlgorithm', 'SSECustomerKey', 'SSECustomerKeyMD5', 'RequestPayer', 'ExpectedBucketOwner']

ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS = ['ACL', 'CacheControl', 'ChecksumAlgorithm', 'ContentDisposition', 'ContentEncoding', 'ContentLanguage', 'ContentType', 'ExpectedBucketOwner', 'Expires', 'GrantFullControl', 'GrantRead', 'GrantReadACP', 'GrantWriteACP', 'Metadata', 'ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus', 'ObjectLockMode', 'ObjectLockRetainUntilDate', 'RequestPayer', 'ServerSideEncryption', 'StorageClass', 'SSECustomerAlgorithm', 'SSECustomerKey', 'SSECustomerKeyMD5', 'SSEKMSKeyId', 'SSEKMSEncryptionContext', 'Tagging', 'WebsiteRedirectLocation']
```

Comment: This is likely wrong? The docs `Copy()` API Call mentions that it allows `ALLOWED_DOWNLOAD_ARGS`, but you linked `ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS`. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/copy.html#

Comment: At the time of writing this question that wasn't written yet https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/1.16.55/boto3/s3/inject.py#L348. Looks like the answer is outdated. Thanks for pointing out! I'll update it to point to the most recent one.

Comment: Interestingly, I think the docs are actually wrong! This code seems to work ```extra_args = {"Tagging": urlencode(s3_tags), "TaggingDirective": "REPLACE"}
dst_bucket.copy({"Bucket": src_bucket.name, "Key": src_key}, dest_key, ExtraArgs=extra_args)```